# Placing child element on top of sibling element

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I want to place my child element on top of my sibling element without changing any of the written css. I can add anything extra required but cannot remove anything.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='sibling'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='sibling'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sibling{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:sticky;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:green;
  margin:4px;
}

.child{
  width:30px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to give the second sibling a lower `z-index` than the first.

Comment: Having a large number of siblings and giving z index to each of them doesnt seem to be a good approach? Is there any other way?

Comment: Adding a single class to each sibling (or using an existing class) and adding a CSS rule with the lower `z-index` seems like a pretty simple solution to me. There are other solutions, but I can't think of any that are as simple as just setting a `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving the second `sibling` type element a `z-index` lower than the first one like so :-

```css
.sibling{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:sticky;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:green;
  margin:4px;
}

.sibling:nth-of-type(1){
  z-index:2
}

.sibling:nth-of-type(2){
  z-index:1;
}

.child{
  width:30px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='sibling'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='sibling'>
</div>
```

Comment: Having a large number of siblings and giving z index to each of them doesnt seem to be a good approach? Is there any other way?